# Line by line value assigning in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I know the title might not be very explicit, sorry, I can't find a better one.

I'm trying to do the following

```
foo<-123456                         # what this is doesn't really matter, just know it's a value
ifelse(my_df$number / foo < 0.75,   #for each row of my_df, see if number / sum is under 0.75
       ifelse(                      # if it is...
         my_df$number / foo < 0.5,  # check if it is under 0.5
         my_df$class<-"in50",       # if it is, assign the value "in50" in the "class" field of this row              
         my_df$class<-"in75"),      # else, assign "in75" to the class field of this row             
       my_df$class<-"in100")        # if it's not under 0.75, assign "in100" to the class field of this row
```

My problem is with the assigning operator :

If I use `<-` the whole `class` column ends up being `in100` (because the last value should be `in100`).

If I use `=`, I get this :

> Error: unexpected '=' in: "my_df$number / sum < 0.5, my_df$class="

And obviously, `==` is not what I need.

Any advice ?

EDIT : I commented the code to make the expected result clearer

Comment: You don't need `my_df$class <-` within the `ifelse`.  You can use `findInterval` i.e. `with(my_df, findInterval(number, c(0.5, 0.75)))`

Comment: You probably need function `cut`.

Comment: Avoid using function names as variable names `sum()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `findInterval`

```
 i1 <- with(my_df, findInterval(number/foo, c(0.5, 0.75))) 
 my_df$class <- c('in50', 'in75', 'in100')[i1+1L]
 head(my_df$class)
 #[1] "in50"  "in50"  "in100" "in100" "in100" "in100"

 head(my_df$number/foo)
 #[1] 0.472 0.360 1.128 0.832 1.064 1.480
```

#### data

```
 foo <- 125  
 set.seed(24)
 my_df <- data.frame(number= sample(1:200, 
                                   100, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: It gives me `1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 0 (and so on..)`

Comment: @Malimalo Have you checked the output of the second line

Comment: Alright, it works, thanks ! Could you explain a bit how it works though, please ?

Comment: @Malimalo Sorry, I was away from my laptop.  It works by creating a grouping numeric index for values that fall within the 0.5, or 0.75 interval.

Comment: No problem. Thanks. So it assigns a `0` value if it's under 0.5, `1` if it's between 0.5 and 0.75, and `2` if it's above, right ? And what's the use of the `[i1+1L]` part ?

Comment: @Malimalo The 'i1' returns values 0, 1, 2.  In `R`, the numeric indexing starts from 1.  So added `1` (the integer represenation is `1L` - could be faster in some cases)

Comment: Thanks. Another question : how would I do the same thing, but based not on intervals but the value of another column : if the value in column A is (in50, in75, in100) have the value in column B multiplied by (0.5, 0.75, 1) respectively ?

Comment: @Malimalo `with(df1, as.numeric(sub('\\D+', '', A))/100*B)`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to accept answer, it's done. As for my new question, I understand this workaround, but it answers only the SO-simplified version of my question :) I posted a new one here, would appreciate it if you could have a look : http://stackoverflow.com/q/35224147/4348534 . Thanks