# Replace a value in a dataframe with a value in another column, based on a condition on a third column

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

My dataframe:

```
class     columnA

foo       10
bar       14.2
hello     48695
bar       4
foo       -7
```

I'm trying to do the following :

```
if (my_df$class== "foo") {
  my_df$columnB <- my_df$columnA * 2
}else{
  if (my_df$class == "bar") {
    my_df$columnB <- my_df$columnA * 5
  }else{
    my_df$columnB <- my_df$columnA * 10
  }
}
```

EDIT : I also tried this :

```
ifelse (my_df$class== "foo",
  my_df$columnB <- my_df$columnA * 2  
  ifelse (my_df$class== "bar",
    my_df$columnB <- my_df$columnA * 5,
    my_df$columnB <- my_df$columnA * 10
  )
)
```

As it doesn't work, let me state it in pseudo-code :

```
for each row, 
    if the value in column class is "foo"
         set the value in column B to be 2 times the value in column A
    if the value in column class is "bar"
         set the value in column B to be 5 times the value in column A
    if the value in column class is something else
         set the value in column B to be 10 times the value in column A
```

My problem is, of course, with the assigning operator : if I use `<-` the whole `columnB` column ends up being `columnA` multiplied by `5` (because it so happens that the `class` value of the last row is `bar`).

Any solution ?

I'll take a solution that solves my problem without going through this `if/elseif/else` syntax, but I'd also really appreciate it if someone could provide a solution keeping this syntax, for the sake of learning.

Thanks

Comment: could you give us a sample of your data (using `dput()`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if` isnt vectorised so  you can try to use `ifelse`

for example

```
my_df$columnB=ifelse(my_df$class== "foo",my_df$columnA * 2, 
                 ifelse(my_df$class == "bar",my_df$columnA * 5,my_df$columnA * 10))
```

Comment: Damn I'm an idiot... See my edited question to see the similar thing I also tried, that obviously had the same problem with the assigning operator. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

With dplyr package you can do it like this:

```
my_df <- my_df %>%
mutate(columnB = ifelse(class == "foo", columnA*2,
                 ifelse(class == "bar", columnA*5, columnA*10)
                 )
       )
```

Comment: I don't know how large your data is so this might not matter, but this could also be the fastest solution offered so far (though data.table probably prevails). dplyr is good to learn early on! Very intuitive and neat.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a nested `ifelse`, you can also use a combination of indexing and math :

```
indx <- (mydf$class == "foo") + 1L + (mydf$class == "bar")*2
mydf$colB <- mydf$columnA*c(10, 2, 5)[indx]
```

which gives:

```
> mydf
  class columnA   colB
1   foo    10.0     20
2   bar    14.2     71
3 hello 48695.0 486950
4   bar     4.0     20
5   foo    -7.0    -14
```